# Can't adjust spacing of UIBarButtonItem(s) when assigned to navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

This is a weird problem.

The situation is that I want to adjust the spacing between my UIBarButtonItem(s) so that they are just 2 pixels apart.

I am able to do this quite easily with UIToolbar:

```
 // Make bottom button bar buttons
 NSMutableArray *bottomButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

 // Create spacer between buttons
 UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
 [bottomButtons addObject:spacer];
 UIBarButtonItem* noSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
 noSpace.width = -10;


 // Add button 1
 self.addAlbumButton = [UIGlossyButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [self.addAlbumButton setTitle:@"Button 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [self.addAlbumButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addAlbum:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 self.addAlbumBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.addAlbumButton];
 [bottomButtons addObject:self.addAlbumBarButton];

 [bottomButtons addObject:noSpace];

 // Add button2
 self.downloadAllItemsButton = [UIGlossyButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [self.downloadAllItemsButton setTitle:@"Button 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [self.downloadAllItemsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downloadAllItemsAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 self.downloadAllItemsBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.downloadAllItemsButton];
 [bottomButtons addObject:self.downloadAllItemsBarButton];

 // add all button to bottom toolbar
 [self.bottomToolbar setItems:bottomButtons];
```

The problem is when I try to do this with the navigationbar.  For some reason, when I insert a fixed length button (with a negative value), it won't shrink the space between the buttons.  I know the fixed length button is there and working because if I change the width to a positive number, the spacing between the buttons increases.

The code is basically the same except that instead of adding the buttons to self.bottomToolbar, I'm calling the following code:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = bottomButtons;
```

I have found the same issue with the MasterViewController.  I'm using a splitviewcontroller and the bottom toolbar works fine but the top toolbar has the same spacing problem.  That problem, is I can't make the space between buttons less than the default.

It seems like navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems works differently than all other toolbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after adding all navigationButtonItem in to an array you can do it like the following way. i guess this will help you also coz this works for me and if you want to change space between button you can change it with help of macro

```
#define ONE_BUTTON_WIDTH 30.0f
#define SPACE_BETWEEN_BUTTONS 12.0f
#define ONE_BUTTON_TOTAL_WIDTH (ONE_BUTTON_WIDTH + SPACE_BETWEEN_BUTTONS)
#define kBookmarksImage [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmarks.png"]

/* CREATE BOOKMARKS BUTTON */
    UIButton *bookmarksButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kBookmarksImage.size.width, kBookmarksImage.size.height)];
    [bookmarksButton setImage:kBookmarksImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [bookmarksButton addTarget:target action:@selector(toolbarButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    bookmarksButton.tag = kBookmarksButtonTag;

UIBarButtonItem *bookmarksButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:bookmarksButton];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
spacer.width = SPACE_BETWEEN_BUTTONS;
[buttons addObjectsFromArray:@[bookmarksButtonItem,spacer]];


 /* ADD ALL THESE BUTTONS TO CUSTOM TOOLBAR AND TOOLBAR TO NAVIGATION BAR */
UIToolbar *customToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, ([bottomButtons count]/2*ONE_BUTTON_TOTAL_WIDTH), 44.01f)]; // 44.01 shifts it up 1px for some reason

customToolbar.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
customToolbar.clipsToBounds = NO;
customToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.305f alpha:0.0f]; // closest I could get by eye to black, translucent style.
customToolbar.barStyle = -1; // clear background
[customToolbar setItems: bottomButtons animated:NO];

UIBarButtonItem *customUIBarButtonitem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customToolbar];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customUIBarButtonitem;
```

Comment: This does work and it what I was doing before.  What I'm trying to do is to adjust the spacing to 2 pixels WITHOUT having to create a new UIToolbar.  It seems like I should be able to use self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems and place in the correct spacer objects. This method allows me to add all the proper components, but it's not working when I am adding the items to the nav bar.  Other toolbars work fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: I can't really find a better way of doing this, so I'm marking your answer as the correct answer.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way just create a method to set up UIButton for each UIBarButtonItem like so:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem*)createAddAlbumBarButtonWithImage:(NSString*)imageName
{
    UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(addAlbum:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem* barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    return barButton;
}
```